# Build error: [NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] - why and how do I fix it?

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

Using MagicalRecord with FTASync; this is a line that I changed (at Saul Mora's recommendation) to make it thread safe.

```
    [[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] MR_saveErrorHandler:^(NSError *error){  //  1.9.0
    [[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] rollback];
    self.syncInProgress = NO;
    self.progressBlock = nil;
    self.progress = 0;

    [self handleError:error];
    return;
}];
```

I'm getting a build error on the first line:  "expected Identifier" at **[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext]**.  No build error on the second line .  My question is: why? and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `localContext`? Is it a variable?

Comment: yes... Core Data - context for all operations...

Comment: You should know how to use a variable by now: `[localContext rollback];`.

Comment: The things you should put inside [] are a receiver followed by a message.  What you have looks like a pointer declaration.

Comment: @rick:  they are separate instances! and I do know how to use variables; I just don't understand why I got the build error on the first line, and not the second.  I'm making changes to FTASync because the original statement is not thread safe, and Saul suggested I make the changes now.

Comment: @PhillipMills: yes, that's exactly what they are... why the error on the first line and not the second then?

Comment: @spokane-dude The syntax makes no sense. 1st off, `NSManagedObjectContext` doesn't have a method named `localContext`. 2nd, what is with the asterisk in the middle of the method call?

Comment: @spokane-dude: `[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext]` really makes no sense in both places. I strongly assume that if you fix it in the first line then the compiler will complain about the second line. - If you give a link to where your found this recommendation it might be easier to find the solution for you.

Comment: @rmaddy  a pilot error on my part!  [NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] should be (NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)... I didn't see the parenthesis!  And Rick, I have never seen a method call like that either... I should have thought it through and looked more carefully what I was doing... sorry for the very lame question!  :-{  Can you re-write the comment as a question so I can close this embarrassment?

Comment: @spokane-dude It's not valid as `(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)` either. What is the data type of `localContext`? What are you trying to do with the `NSManagedObjectContext` part?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to follow Saul's instructions: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535419/what-is-the-replacement-method-for-this-magicalrecord-deprecated-call

This is where **localContext** is defined in AppDelegate.h:  NSManagedObjectContext *localContext;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] MR_saveErrorHandler:^(NSError *error){  //  1.9.0
[[NSManagedObjectContext *localContext] rollback];
```

to

```
[localContext MR_saveErrorHandler:^(NSError *error){  //  1.9.0
[localContext rollback];
```

Comment: Won't build... getting error: 
**No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares the selector 'MR_saveErrorHandler:**

Comment: make sure #import "MagicalRecord+CoreData.h" is somewhere in the headers for this file. You're not finding symbols, that's all.

Comment: Uh... I think you meant "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h", yes? (because the other doesn't exist)... and it still won't build.  I did a search (XCode 5) for **MR_saveErrorHandler** and it doesn't exist.  Do I have the correct version? (how do I tell which version I have?)

Comment: Use the NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord headers or autocomplete to help you out here. But, I think that method was removed in the most recent release. Try one of the other MR_save* methods...