# Why does this app crash if I'm testing for the cause and bypassing the offending code?

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord-2.2

I have this code where I'm trying to get all records for a certain key:

```
//  if the apptObject.aApptKey is nil, skip it...
if(apptObject.aApptKey == nil)
    continue;  //  go to beginning and try again 

    //  using apptObject.aApptKey, get the client's name
NSPredicate *predicate =  ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(aClientKey = %@)", apptObject.aApptKey]);
    clientInfo = [ClientInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate: predicate];
```

The problem is I'm getting this error (courtesy of Crashlytics):

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'ClientInfo'

Either don't understand what the error message is telling me, or I don't understand how it could happen if I'm testing for nil prior to the MR_findAll.  Note that the 'keys' in question are *exactly* the same, I'm just using the appointment key to get the client's name.

Can someone please explain how this could happen?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the predicate. It tells you that the NSManagedObjectContext is nil.

Comment: How could that be when I have this:  **defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];** in AppDelegate **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**?  (I'm not questioning your comment, but I don't understand how it could be) What do I have to change so all classes can use the default context from AppDelegate?

Comment: I don't know how it happens, but as far as I know, MR_contextForCurrentThread is deprecated because it is not "compatible" with the new managed object concurrency types.

Comment: Martin R: please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can close this and give you points... thanks... S-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(From my comment:)* The error message has nothing to do with the predicate.
It tells you that the `NSManagedObjectContext` is `nil`.

A possible problem could be the `MR_contextForCurrentThread` method
which is deprecated
and should not be used anymore. The reason is that it assumes a unique *thread* for each
managed object context. This is no longer true with the new MOC concurrency types which
run on GCD *queues*.
Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/20536335/1187415.

Better use `MR_defaultContext` or pass the context from one view controller to the next.