# core data difference between findfirstbyattribute and findfirstbyattribute in context

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

What's the difference between these two ways of fetching an object in Core Data? Is one more efficient than the other? Do they do the same thing?

```
MR_findFirstByAttribute:(NSString *) withValue:(id) inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)
```

vs

```
MR_findFirstByAttribute:(NSString *) withValue:(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing, it's just that one allows you to supply a context and the other goes and gets the context for the current thread (`[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]`). If you already have the appropriate context then it's more efficient to supply it yourself.

Comment: And `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]` is deprecated (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535419/what-is-the-replacement-method-for-this-magicalrecord-deprecated-call) so you should not use the second method at all.

Comment: @MartinR is [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]; deprecated as well? Is there ever a reason to access the managedobjectcontext when using magical record?