# Disposing of NSManagedObjectContexts in a Core Data management class

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, frameworks, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So I am making a framework to hold all the code used to manipulate a core data database. What I have ended up having an issue with is this.

I have a method which returns a new item

```
- (NSManagedObject *)createItem;
```

once they have modified that item the would call

```
- (void)save;
```

This has to be able to be executed in multiple threads so the managed object I return from my method has to have an NSManagedObjectContext consistent inside a thread. My solution to solve this was to create a NSMutableDictionary to hold a references to NSManagedObjectContexts using

```
[NSThread hash]
```

as the key. This works great. The only problem is that I cannot get rid of the contexts once their threads have finished.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could detect that?

Here is the code for my managed object context method

```
// Return Managed Object Context for Framework
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    // Get Thread Hash Value
    NSThread * currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    NSNumber * hashValue = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[currentThread hash]];

    // Get Context From Thread Hash
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self.managedObjectContexts objectForKey:hashValue];

    // Check Context Exists
    if (!context)
    {
        // Create Managed Object Context With Persistent Store Coordinator In Main Thread
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil) {
            context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }

        // Add Context To Available Contexts
        [self.managedObjectContexts setObject:context forKey:hashValue];
    }

    // Return
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using the `threadDictionary` available on each `NSThread`. In this way you can easily get the MOC for a thread (or know if there isn't one) and the cleanup will be handled for you.

Comment: Dang had no idea that existed I will try this out and let you know you may have just save the day.

Comment: for a popular implementation example, see MR_contextForCurrentThread in https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/eedf65161acdc2645c2f7c6e0b07360790244f35/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalThreading.m

Comment: @magma: MR_contextForCurrentThread is deprecated, see this post from the author of MagicalRecord: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20536335/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR excellent remark, thank you very much. I was unaware of that.