# Magical Record What is the difference in deleting all records with context and without context

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

It could be a very basic question.  I see two ways to delete the records from Core Data. I am using Magical Record library.

Option 1:

```
[myEntityName truncateAll]
```

option 2:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
[myEntityName truncateAllInContext:localContext];
```

What is the difference between these two? From the second option i could sense that the deletion happens in the current thread.  If so,  what is that impacts if i use 'truncateAll'?

Kindly advice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535419/what-is-the-replacement-method-for-this-magicalrecord-deprecated-call: `contextForCurrentThread` is deprecated and should not be used. It does not play well with the "new" managed object context concurrency types.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to file `CoreData+MagicalRecord.m`, you will see that `truncateAll:` calls `truncateAllInContext:`

```
+ (BOOL) MR_truncateAll
{
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    [self MR_truncateAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop

    return YES;
}
```

What means that `truncateAll:` allows you to call `truncateAllInContext:` without having to specify the context for the current thread as a parameter.

Comment: Please stop using contextForCurrentThread. We've deprecated that method as its prone to crashing when using GCD rather than threads for concurrency support.