# Magical record deprecated method

Tags: ios, deprecated, magicalrecord

what is the alternative for this deprecated method

- `MR_saveWithErrorCallback`
- `MR_resetContextForCurrentThread`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20536335/1770453

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the replacement method for this MagicalRecord deprecated call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535419/what-is-the-replacement-method-for-this-magicalrecord-deprecated-call)

Comment: Flagged as duplicate

Comment: its not about MR_contextForCurrentThread