# how to upgrade magical record sdk using cocoa pods in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa

last week i integrated Magical Record 2.3.2 beta version.. but i was tried to integrate Magical Record 2.3.3 latest version. but i got failure.. so finally i integrated Magical Record 2.3.2 beta sdk. but now i need to update from Magical Record 2.3.2 to Magical Record 2.3.3 sdk.. in my project having pod file..so through terminal i am doing like this:

1) Open Terminal

2)  Write CD command.. and Drag and Drop my project folder  -> press enter

3) Write Command open - e podfile

now open the pod file.. In pod file i am updating magical record sdk like this  “pod ‘MagicalRecord’, :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => '2.3.3'”

4) After that i am updating my pod file like this  “pod update”

in terminal i got these error messages..

[!] Error installing MagicalRecord [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git /var/folders/qy/ks1z12x94zg5998_1kb9w0vc0000gn/T/d20160310-728-jkxwbm --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.3.3
Cloning into '/var/folders/qy/ks1z12x94zg5998_1kb9w0vc0000gn/T/d20160310-728-jkxwbm'... warning: Could not find remote branch 2.3.3 to clone. fatal: Remote branch 2.3.3 not found in upstream origin

please help me any body.. how to solve these issue.why magical record 2.3.3 is not integrated.is there any issues.?? Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are not using the good tag version. It should be **v**2.3.3 :

```
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => 'v2.3.3'
```

Comment: Thank u so much bro.. it is integrated successfully.. but i got some warning messages like this "‘MR_ContextForCurrentThread’ is deprecated: This method will be removed in MagicalRecord 3.0"

Comment: :) You have now to use the class method saveWithBlock: of the MagicalRecord class (so replace the MR_ContextForCurrentThread calls everywhere in your code). Exemple : [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                User *localUser = [user MR_inContext:localContext];
                localUser.firstName = @"Whavever you want I know";
            }];

Comment: You may want to refer to this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535419/what-is-the-replacement-method-for-this-magicalrecord-deprecated-call

Comment: @Tenguy G. I am writing like this "[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]" so can i modified this one to this one "[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    //make your changes in the localContext
}];
"

Comment: @Tenguy G. i am writing like this in constants.h file "#define CURRENTTHREAD_CONTEXT [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) { }];" so i have some issues in project.. i am just using this method CURRENTTHREAD_CONTEXT in my project. so in one of the class i am writing like this    SystemPreferences *preference = [SystemPreferences MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:CURRENTTHREAD_CONTEXT]; so i got some issue i.e Expected expression ']'

Comment: If you are going to edit and save the SystemPreferences preference object then it will be something like [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {  [SystemPreferences MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext]; }];  . If you just want to consult it without modifying it, just use [ [SystemPreferences MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106898/discussion-between-satya-and-tanguy-g).

Comment: come to chat. i have some doubt